# Function if and for loop for even numbers in const array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i have exercise like this : You have the table: `const numbers = [2, 5, 7, 10, 34, 16, 879, 1]`. Write a function that will print in the console a new table containing only even numbers from the numbers table. And mine solution is :               
`function evenNumbers(numbers){
for ( let num of numbers)
if (num / 2) }`
I don't know is that function "if" is correct for "even" numbers, i also don't know for sure that i grab "const numbers" to function. i hope for a help 
so now with "filter" i have :`function evenNumbers(number){
return number % 2 === 0}
const parzyste = numbers.filter(evenNumbers)
console.log(parzyste)` 
is that correct after edition?

Comment: even numbers would have `num % 2 === 0` - and when you call the function, supply the variable containing the numbers as an argument to the function call

Comment: So instead "if(num/2)" i should give this : "num % 2 === 0"? could you tell me more specify the second part of your tense ?

Comment: Rather than for..of, consider [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `let evens = numbers.filter(num => !(num % 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number is even or odd, you need to check the remainder of it over 2 and to do so you can use `%` operator:

```
if (num%2 === 0) {
    // number is even, because the remainder is 0
}
else {
    // number is odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the even numbers using the condition `num % 2 == 0`

```js
const numbers = [2, 5, 7, 10, 34, 16, 879, 1];

function evenNumbers(numbers) {
  return numbers.filter(n => n % 2 == 0);
}

console.log(evenNumbers(numbers));
```

Alternatively, with if condition as below

```js
const numbers = [2, 5, 7, 10, 34, 16, 879, 1];

function evenNumbers(numbers) {
  let evenNums = [];

  numbers.forEach(n => {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      evenNums.push(n);
    }
  });

  return evenNums;
}

console.log(evenNumbers(numbers));
```